# Why can I get the same result when I change the order of the first yield or remove the second yield?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning the Coroutines of Kotlin.

The following code is from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html

1: Why can I get the same result when I change the order of the first `yield`? You can see *Image A1* and *Image A2*.

In my mind, the following code in *Image A2* will get the following result. I think the Code `yield()` in *Image A2* will be temporarily deprioritises the current CPU task, giving other tasks `job` a fair opportunity to run.

```
  //Image A2 Code
  yield()
  println("2. Cancelling child")

  The result I think
  1. Child is cancelled
  2. Cancelling child
  3. Parent is not cancelled
```

2: Why can I get the same result when I remove the second `yield`?  You can see *Image B1* and *Iamge B2*.

**Image A1**
[image]

**Image A2**
[image]

**Image B1**
[image]

**Image B2**
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Try printing something inside the `try` block (before calling `delay`) and you will see the difference between A1 and A2.

Comment: To get an answer to "why?" you first have to present your expectation, and a reasoning for it. The output looks like I would expect it to.

Comment: Your `child` coroutine is being delayed almost forever. It won't execute the `finally` block until you cancel it. Not to mention the call to `delay` itself which would return the execution to the next instruction after the first `yield` printing "2. Cancelling child" first. I insist, print anything inside the `try` block instead of delaying and you will see the difference.

Comment: You seem to think that `child cancelled` will print before you even reach the line `child.cancel()`. It is still beyond me what reasoning may have led you to believe that.